# How to add shadow with Beizer Path

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, shadow

I have added shadow to 3 sides of a view not given bottom shadow, but at initial load, it shows shadow to all the corners but when I scroll it shows correct result. this is my code.

class ScheduleClassesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
let path = UIBezierPath()

//MARK:-
//MARK:- IBOUTLETS

@IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var openTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var closeTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var clockImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var instructerNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var classTypeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var healthClubLocationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ratingsBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var locationBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var healthClubName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var healthClubLoc: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!

//MARK:-
//MARK:- TableView Life Cycle

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.healthClubLoc.isHidden = false
    self.ratingsBtn.doCorner(cornerRadius: 2.5)
    self.locationBtn.doCorner(cornerRadius: 2.5)
    self.ratingsBtn.setBorder(with: UIColor.gray, of: 0.5)
    self.locationBtn.setBorder(with: UIColor.white, of: 1.0)
    self.cellImage.doCorner(cornerRadius: 2.5)
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    self.shadowView.layoutIfNeeded()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: shadowView.frame.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowView.frame.size.width, y: 0.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowView.frame.size.width, y: shadowView.frame.size.height))
    self.shadowView.drawShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.red, shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowPath: path, shadowRadius: 2, cornerRadius: 0.0)

}
```

[before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tukZ.png)

[image: before scrolling]

[after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfKSm.png)

[image: after scrolling]

Answer (score 1):

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: shadowView.frame.size.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowView.frame.size.width, y: 0.0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: shadowView.frame.size.width, y: shadowView.frame.size.height))
    self.shadowView.drawShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.red, shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowPath: path, shadowRadius: 2, cornerRadius: 0.0)
    layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Please update your code

Comment: Please help in removing bottom corner red shadow.